# Custom Segue Animation showing black screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboardsegue, catransition

I am struck with a new problem, on presenting the `destinationViewController` using custom segue, during transition the source `ViewController` is changed to black screen, i need the screen to be as it is (my design).

```
UIViewController *sourceViewController = (UIViewController*)[self sourceViewController];
UIViewController *destinationController = (UIViewController*)[self destinationViewController][screenshot][1]

CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.1;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionPush; //kCATransitionMoveIn; //, kCATransitionPush, kCATransitionReveal, kCATransitionFade
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight; //kCATransitionFromLeft, kCATransitionFromRight, kCATransitionFromTop, kCATransitionFromBottom


[destinationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
[sourceViewController presentViewController:destinationController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to keep the context, try this:

```
    UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController;
    rootViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    UIViewController *destinationController = (UIViewController*)[self destinationViewController]
    [sourceViewController presentViewController:destinationController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: Hi,i am struck while doing the reverse operation. i wanna go to the first screen back from the second screen with the same animation i discussed above but struck with "The first screen comes immediately and then then animation of the first screen slowly coming and overlaping". i just wanna animate the first screen over the second screen

Comment: how are you doing that?

Comment: how can one do this in swift?